# Как написать правильный редирект 301 в файле htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать правильный редирект 301 в файле .htaccess, для сервера Apache.

Если заходят по адресу [http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/lechenie-narkomanii/лечение-зависимости-от-лирики](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/lechenie-narkomanii/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8) то идет редирект на туже страницу, только в **конце добавляется слеш** [http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/lechenie-narkomanii/лечение-зависимости-от-лирики/](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/lechenie-narkomanii/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/)

но при этом, если страница заканчивается на .html, например http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/lechenie-narkomanii.html то **слэш не добавляется** в конец.

**Помогите составить правильное условие.**

Comment: А редирект тут причем ?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то Вам необходимо смотреть на mod_rewrite - (Модуль mod_rewrite имеющийся в составе Apache — это мощнейшее, интеллектуальное средство преобразования URL адресов. С ним возможны почти все типы преобразований, которые могут выполняться или нет в зависимости от разных условий, факторов...).

Comment: @kohana, по-моему, нужно делать редирект.

@Вячеслав Кириченко,я это понимаю, можете помочь составить правильную запись?

Comment: Помогу, только не сейчас. Пропадает электричество. Извините, у нас война. Надеюсь, завтра посмотрю и подскажу.